# How can i put a logo partially over an image and then have text over the image

Tags: html, css, image

I have a theme that has markup like this:

```
<div class="logo">
   <a id="logo" href="http://test.rudtek.com" title="test">
        <img class="logo-main scale-with-grid" src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/seasons_management_logo.jpg" alt="seasons_management_logo">
    </a>
    <div class="containerBox">
        <img class="img-responsive" <img="" src="/wp-content/uploads/revslider/slider-home-4/img-slider-4-3-825x510.jpg">
        <div class="text-box">
            <p class="dataNumber">Home 4</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This gives me an image like this:
[image]

BUt what I really want it to look like is this:

[image]

Size ratio isn't the most important here, but I can't fiture out how to get the seasons logo to go over the dear image.

This is my css:

```
.containerBox {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.text-box {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto;
}

.dataNumber {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can absolutely position `#logo` over `.containerBox` and give `#logo` a `z-index` so it will stack on top, then use a `margin-left` on `.containerBox` to push it to the right.

```css
.containerBox {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.text-box {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto;
}

.dataNumber {
  margin-top: auto;
}

/* added these styles */
.logo {
  position: relative;
}
#logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em; left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: white;
}
.containerBox {
  margin-left: 100px;
}

/* you don't need this, just for this pepsi logo which is huge */
#logo img {
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <a id="logo" href="http://test.rudtek.com" title="test">
    <img class="logo-main scale-with-grid" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/f7/aa/ed/f7aaed9fcacfe6df89cef0a16cf06266.png" alt="seasons_management_logo">
  </a>
  <div class="containerBox">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png">
    <div class="text-box">
      <p class="dataNumber">Home 4</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: AWESOME.  That definitely puts me close to where I need to be!  Thank you for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Michael beat me to it, but here's another method.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VpErXP

```
.logo {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}
#logo img {
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.containerBox {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.text-box {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto;
}

.dataNumber {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```